# How to package shell programs into an AppImage?

Tags: appimage

I have made an AppImage via:

```
linuxdeploy --appdir AppDir --icon-file icon.png --desktop-file desktop.desktop --executable myExecutable --output appimage
```

which runs fine.  However, the program I've packaged (`myExecutable`) makes shell calls (say to `shellProgram1`, `shellProgram2`, ...) at run-time to make use of various programs that aren't necessarily on every distro.

**Question:** Does `linuxdeploy` (or some other AppImage utility) provide an easy way to package these programs into the AppImage, so that when `myExecutable` calls them at run-time, they are guaranteed to be available?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve such thing you need to deploy all the binaries that may not be present in all distros into the AppDir and set the PATH environment to make them available at runtime.

With `linuxdeploy` you have to manually copy the files into the AppDir and create a wrapper for the main binary to set the PATH. Something like this

```
$!/bin/bash
export PATH="$APPDIR/usr/bin:$PATH"

exec $APPDIR/usr/bin/my_program
```

You can also use [appimage-builder](https://github.com/appimagecrafters/appimage-builder) which creates such wrapper for you. In the [project examples folder](https://github.com/AppImageCrafters/appimage-builder/blob/master/examples/wget/AppImageBuilder.yml), you can find several recipes that can be used for inspiration.